# How to compare in SelectList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCreate() {
// Setup
AdvertisementController controller = new AdvertisementController();
ViewResult result = controller.Create() as ViewResult;
var expectedCategories = new SelectList(new[] { "Electronics", "Toys", "Books", "Sporting Goods" });
// Execute
var actualCategories = result.ViewBag.categoryList;
// Assert
Assert.IsNotNull(result); 
Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories[0], actualCategories[0]);
Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories[1], actualCategories[2]);
Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories[2], actualCategories[3]);
Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories[3], actualCategories[4]);
Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories[4], actualCategories[5]);
                            }
```

This assert does not work correctly. How do I compare `result.ViewBag` and the actual `SelectList`?

Answer (score 1):

Assert should actually work check by doing lower case to both params.

I.e.

Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories[0].ToLower(), actualCategories[0].ToLower());

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
// Execute
var actualCategories = (SelectList)result.ViewBag.categoryList;

// Assert
Assert.IsNotNull(result); 
Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories.Count(), actualCategories.Count());
for (var i = 0; i < expectedCategories.Count(); i++)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories.ElementAt(i).Value, actualCategories.ElementAt(i).Value);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedCategories.ElementAt(i).Text, actualCategories.ElementAt(i).Text);
}
```

Comment: this is not work it gives many errors like   Error 1 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake and now updated my answer. Try again with the new code. It should be `.Count()` instead of `Length`.

Comment: Error 1 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count'   it gives the same error for the Count()

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` in order to bring the extension method to scope.

Comment: when I add using System.Linq;  my all the test methods are failed.before adding it other test cases are works fine..now all are failed????please help me to recover..

Comment: when I add using System.Linq; my all the test methods are failed.before adding it other test cases are works fine..now all are failed????please help me to recover.. –